# Spring Kafka @DltHandler annotated method is not receiving headers correctly in Non-Blocking retries implementation

Tags: spring, kotlin, error-handling, spring-kafka, kafka-dlt

I’m trying to implement a Non-Blocking Retries with Spring Kafka. According to documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic), we could set up a handler method to process messages from a DLT topic, after the exhausted tries, set up in @KafkaListnener, have been done. My intend is capture some headers on DLT handler method as demonstrated in the following code:

```
@DltHandler
    fun processaDlt(
        @Payload mensagem: String,
        @Header("event") eventName: String,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.ORIGINAL_OFFSET) offset: String,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.EXCEPTION_FQCN) descException: String,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE) stacktrace: String,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.EXCEPTION_MESSAGE) errorMessage: String
    ) {
```

But, some headers were not coming correctly, or was not coming at all. I've tried some values for these headers, like KafkaHeaders.DLT_ORIGINAL_OFFSET, KafkaHeaders.OFFSET, etc. I saw in Spring Kafka code that some headers are prefixed with the string "kafka_" and I saw these values on the messages that are forward to xpto-dlt topic after unsuccessful retries, **but the values of some headers are truncated**, as:

> kafka_original-offset: �, kafka_original-partition: , kafka_original-timestamp: {�*XR, kafka_original-timestamp-type: CreateTime, kafka_original-topic: xpto-topic, retry_topic-attempts: , retry_topic-backoff-timestamp: {�*�@, retry_topic-original-timestamp: {�*XR

My listen method that consume the original messages are anotated as following code:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = xpto-topic, groupId = my-group-to-xpto)
fun listen(@Payload mensagem: String,
           @Header("event") event: String,
           @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) offset: Long,
           @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER)  consumer: KafkaConsumer<String, String>,
           @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) timestamp: Long
) {
```

After all, which headers the method annotated with @DltHandler can accept? Why some values have the values truncated?

Obs:

- The codes above are in Kotlin with Spring Boot
- I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.4-RELEASE and:

> compile 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.7.6'

> compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.8.0'

Answer (score 1):

These headers are converted from `byte[]`.

It looks like there is a conversion problem on the offset - when I declare the parameter as `long`, it returns zero.

This works fine for me...

```java
@RetryableTopic(attempts = "1")
@KafkaListener(id = "so69229529", topics = "so69229529")
void listen(String in) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}

@DltHandler
void handler(Message<?> msg,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.ORIGINAL_OFFSET) byte[] offset,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.EXCEPTION_FQCN) String descException,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE) String stacktrace,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.EXCEPTION_MESSAGE) String errorMessage) {
    System.out.println(msg);
    System.out.println(ByteBuffer.wrap(offset).getLong());
    System.out.println(descException);
    System.out.println(stacktrace);
    System.out.println(errorMessage);
}
```

```
4
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.TimestampedException: Listener method 'void com.example.demo.So69229529Application.listen(java.lang.String)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'void com.example.demo.So69229529Application.listen(java.lang.String)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
...
Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.TimestampedException: Listener method 'void com.example.demo.So69229529Application.listen(java.lang.String)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'void com.example.demo.So69229529Application.listen(java.lang.String)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1951