# retry attempts count in consumer error handling in spring-kafka not work

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka with the following configuration:

```
@Component
public class RetryableKafkaListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RetryableKafkaListener.class);
    @RetryableTopic(
        attempts = "1",
        backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 2.0),
        autoCreateTopics = "false",
        topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE
    )
    @KafkaListener(
        id = "shMessage",
        topics = "${topic.name.online}",
        containerFactory = "messageKafkaListenerContainerFactory"
    )
    public void messageListener(ConsumerRecord<?, MessageModel> consumerRecord) {
        LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", consumerRecord.value().toString());
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }
    @DltHandler
    public void dltMessageListener(ConsumerRecord<?, MessageModel> consumerRecord) {
        LOGGER.info("failed payload='{}'", consumerRecord.value().toString());
    }
}
```

I have run this program and expect method `dltMessageListener()` to run after one retry, but this does not happen and the message is given indefinitely to the listener.

Comment: I just wrote a similar app to answer [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69229529/spring-kafka-dlthandler-annotated-method-is-not-receiving-headers-correctly-in/69302622#69302622) and it worked fine for me.  (BTW, `maxAtempts = "1"` means one delivery attempt, not one retry. Use "2" for one retry.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `{topicname}-dlt` topic or make `autoCreateTopics = "true"`. After all retries are exhausted, it will send it to the `{topicname}-dlt` topic.